# How to get the DirectMemorySize

Tags: java

I set the VM options to `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=3M`. Then I ran the springcloud gateway application by IDEA in Java VisualVM. Here are the details of `DirectMemory`:

[image: JVM Params]

[image: MBeans]

So why is MBeans's  `java.nio.BufferPool` incorrect? It shows that the `TotalCapacity` is `5,267`.

Comment: What do you expect it to be?

Comment: Actually, the DirectMemory has been used up，I want to monitor DirectMemory through this indicator.However, this value is not the same as the actual value